# #AskFirebase Toggle source map on/off on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is there any way I can upload the source maps to firebase hosting, and enable\disable them by demand?
I don't want to reveal my source maps on production, but if there's a specific error on production env, I'd like to turn source maps on.
Can this be acheived through cli\api\console?
I was thinking of adding a redirect rule to redirect all source maps requests to a non existent path, but what I cannot figure out is how to enable source maps again. How do I update **only** the firebase.json to fix the broken source map links?

Comment: There is no access control on Firebase Hosting: all files you deploy are accessible to everyone.

Comment: But wouldn't redirect rules prevent others from accessing specific files?

Comment: Having a redirect rule for a path prevents *everyone* from accessing the file(s) at that path.

Comment: Yes, so the question is whether there's a way to update the redirect rules after the files were deployed. So the source map files are not accessible unless I have a good reason to allow access to them. (When there's a problem and I want to debug production)

Comment: There is no way to deploy only your `firebase.json` at the moment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I came up with a solution. I posted it below. Let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution that satisfies me and I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@atlanteh/toggling-sourcemaps-on-firebase-hosting-9fe854eb9410) that describes in details how to do it.

The gist is:

1. Before you deploy your code, move all /static/*.map files to a new secret directory inside your build folder
2. In firebase.json rewrite all /static/*.map requests to a cloud function.
3. Write the function where you can decide whether to redirect to real location of sourcemaps or return 404